Prisma field accepting an array with Postgres database
 model ComponentTag {
  id                        String                      @id @default(uuid())
  title                     String
  components                Component[]                 
  createdAt                 DateTime                    @default(now())
  updatedAt                 DateTime                    @updatedAt
}

model Component {
  id                        String                      @id @default(uuid())
  name                      String                      
  componentTagId            String       
  componentTag              ComponentTag                @relation(fields: 
    [componentTagId], references: [id])
  createdAt                 DateTime                    @default(now())
  updatedAt                 DateTime                    @updatedAt

  @@index([componentCategoryId])
  @@index([componentTagId])
  @@index([licenseId])

}
I am trying to make the componentTag field accept an array of strings, but it seems that Postgres has limitations in Prisma. For example, if I make the componentTagId an array, I get an error saying that the componentTagId field and the id reference do not have the same type. If I try to make the ComponentTag an array, I get an error saying that the operation is not supported with Postgres.
Your help will be extremely appreciated. I appreciate any help you can provide.

I guess you're trying to implement a simple many-to-many relation and according to documentation it should look something like this:
model ComponentTag {
  id         String      @id @default(uuid())
  components Component[] @relation("ComponentOnComponentTag")
  ...
}

model Component {
  id   String         @id @default(uuid())
  tags ComponentTag[] @relation("ComponentOnComponentTag")
  ...
}


Thanks. It worked just fine until I added the componentTagId field and id reference to it.  When I add them to the field, I get an error saying: Error validating: Embedded many-to-many relations are not supported on Postgres. Please use the syntax defined in https://pris.ly/d/relational-database-many-to-many

But why do you need componentTagId in Component model once you'll already have tags?
